# How to set user input Strings into ENUM Java

Tags: java, string, input, enums

So I want the user to input user input strings and store them into an ENUM but I'm not sure how to store the new strings in the ENUM.

```
public enum Food {
  PIZZA("", "", ""),

private final String location;
private final String calories;
private final String fat;

Food(String location, String calories, String fat){
    this.location = location;
    this.calories= calories;
    this.fat= fat;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String location = input.nextLine();
String calories= input.nextLine();
String fat= input.nextLine();

Food(location, calories, fat);
```

I don't think the Food(location, calories, fat); sets the input in the enum, what could I use in order to set it?

Comment: Why do you want it to be an enum? Why not just a regular class?

Comment: Enums are best used for immutable data, usually type information. It would make more sense if `Food` were a contract, like an interface or abstract class, rather than being implemented as an enum.

Comment: You should rename your enum to FoodType and use a class (such as Food). enum should be immutable or at least be able to recompute their state (for instance, you won't get the location, calories and fat stored using serialization).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve by doing this, but you can drop `final` modifier from the enum fields, add getters and setters and store them once user input data. E.g:

```
public enum Food {
    PIZZA;

    private String location;
    private String calories;
    private String fat;

    public String getLocation() { return location; }
    public void setLocation(String location) { this.location = location; }

    public String getCalories() { return calories; }
    public void setCalories(String calories) { this.calories = calories; }

    public String getFat() { return fat; }
    public void setFat(String fat) { this.fat = fat; }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s: %s %s %s", super.toString(), location, calories, fat);
    }
}
```

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Food.PIZZA.setLocation(input.nextLine());
    Food.PIZZA.setCalories(input.nextLine());
    Food.PIZZA.setFat(input.nextLine());

    System.out.println(Food.PIZZA);
}
```

Output

```
locat
calor
fat
PIZZA: locat calor fat
```

Comment: Thank you, I took your advice on dropping the final, and created set methods